# Customer similarity for customer-product interactions over time

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, recommender-system, feature-engineering

I have a table that has 3 columns: Customer, Item and Date of Interaction between customer and item. I would like to calculate a similarity between customers based on how these customers interact with the items considering time.

Usually I would tranform:

`|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Customer       |       Item       |       Date       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          0          |          A       |   01/01/2000     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          0          |          B       |   05/01/2000     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          0          |          B       |   11/01/2000     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |          B       |   06/01/2000     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|`

Into:

`|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Customer       |       Item A     |       Item B     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          0          |          1       |          2       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |          0       |          1       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|`

And calculate similarity based on those vectors.

However, I want to consider time. I want to say that interactions that happened in closer dates are more similar.

My final task is to predict future interactions and I want to do some feature engineering using this similarity. For example, if I know that customer 0 is similar to customer 1 and customer 0 interacted with item A last week, maybe customer 1 is more likely to interact with item A in the following week.

Comment: This question needs more thought and work to be intelligible.

Comment: Sorry, I edited this question and so it might be clearer now

Comment: @jcp please show the data as columns and rows with the time variable clearly labeled. The text tables are confusing.

Comment: If I were to read the *tea leaves* of this question it sounds like a variant of categorical approaches to clustering customers. One way to address this would be to restructure or transform the matrix into customer-time-items where there is one row for each customer for a predetermined period of time (hour, day, week, month, whatever) and then a string of features across the set of all possible items summarizing the activity (possible values ranging from 0,1,2,3...*max* or just 0,1-yes/no) for each item. Possible R modules include polCA or permutation distance clustering (PDC).